# Chart from mysql data not showing while using jqwidgets

Tags: php, mysql, json, charts

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxchart/jquery-chart-data-source.htm

I use my own database with their code, but even there example not drawing Chart on my page.

data.php:

```
<?php
    #Include the connect.php file
    include('connect.php');
    #Connect to the database
    //connection String
    $connect = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    //Select The database
    $bool = mysql_select_db($database, $connect);
    if ($bool === False){
       print "can't find $database";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  `invoices` ORDER BY OrderDate LIMIT 0 , 100";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());

    // get data and store in a json array
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $orders[] = array(
            'OrderDate' => $row['OrderDate'],
            'ProductName' => $row['ProductName'],
            'Quantity' => $row['Quantity']
          );
    }

    echo json_encode($orders);
?>
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<title>Chart</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxchart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxdata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var source =
        {
             datatype: "json",
             datafields: [
                 { name: 'OrderDate', type: 'date'},
                 { name: 'Quantity'},
                 { name: 'ProductName'}
            ],
            url: 'data.php'
        };

       var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source,
        {
            autoBind: true,
            async: false,
            downloadComplete: function () { },
            loadComplete: function () { },
            loadError: function () { }
        });

     // prepare jqxChart settings
        var settings = {
            title: "Orders by Date",
            showLegend: true,
            padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
            titlePadding: { left: 90, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
            source: dataAdapter,
            categoryAxis:
                {
                    text: 'Category Axis',
                    textRotationAngle: 0,
                    dataField: 'OrderDate',
                    formatFunction: function (value) {
                        return $.jqx.dataFormat.formatdate(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                    },
                    showTickMarks: true,
                    tickMarksInterval: Math.round(dataAdapter.records.length / 6),
                    tickMarksColor: '#888888',
                    unitInterval: Math.round(dataAdapter.records.length / 6),
                    showGridLines: true,
                    gridLinesInterval: Math.round(dataAdapter.records.length / 3),
                    gridLinesColor: '#888888',
                    axisSize: 'auto'
                },
            colorScheme: 'scheme05',
            seriesGroups:
                [
                    {
                        type: 'line',
                        valueAxis:
                        {
                            displayValueAxis: true,
                            description: 'Quantity',
                            //descriptionClass: 'css-class-name',
                            axisSize: 'auto',
                            tickMarksColor: '#888888',
                            unitInterval: 20,
                            minValue: 0,
                            maxValue: 100
                        },
                        series: [
                                { dataField: 'Quantity', displayText: 'Quantity' }
                          ]
                    }
                ]
        };

        // setup the chart
        $('#jqxChart').jqxChart(settings);
    });
</script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jqxChart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

data.php outputs data correctly, but chart not appearing on test.html. Even though i see additional syntax code in Web Developer generated source code:

```
<div id="jqxChart">
<table id="tblChart" valign="top" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 0.5px;" colspan="2" id="tdTop">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="tdLeft">
</td>
<td style="width: 1264px; height: 0px;" class="chartContainer">
<svg height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" id="svgChart">
<defs>
<clipPath id="cl1371557944881_1">
<rect height="0" width="1263" y="1" x="1">
</rect>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="cl1371557944881_2">
<rect height="19" width="1165" y="4" x="94">
</rect>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="cl1371557944881_3">
<rect height="16" width="1165" y="21" x="94">
</rect>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<rect stroke="#888888" stroke-width="1" fill="#FFFFFF" height="-1" width="1262" y="1.5" x="1.5">
</rect>
<g clip-path="url(#cl1371557944881_1)">
<g clip-path="url(#cl1371557944881_2)">
<text cursor="default" height="17" width="1163" y="19" x="616" class="jqx-chart-title-text">Orders by Date</text></g>
<g clip-path="url(#cl1371557944881_3)">
<text cursor="default" height="14" width="1163" y="34" x="640" class="jqx-chart-title-description">Description</text>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I don't understand where is the problem. Tried to use older versions of jquery, but the proble, is the same, also checked with FireBug Net and all javascript files are loaded with code 200.

Answer (score 0):

The Chart's Size is not set and that should be the problem. You may set its Width and Height CSS properties.